# JomSocial 2.8.x require minimum Joomla! CMS 2.5.6

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, jomsocial

I have to done the network site, So i am using the Jomsocial component in my web site. Once i will install the pack then the following errors will shown.

1. JomSocial 2.8.x require minimum Joomla! CMS 2.5.6
2. Component Install: Custom install routine failure
3. Error installing component

But i have using Joomla 2.5.10 latest pack only. So anyone please help me.

Comment: Try upgrading to Joomla 2.5.14 to see if that fixes the issue

Comment: Thanks for a response.. Actually i am already tried the way, but still it's not working.. Any other idea

Comment: Also why would you be using Jomsocial 2.8.x? It's old. Try upgrading to the latest version of JomSocial 3.0.4

Comment: which leads me to my next question, did you buy JomSocial or download it from a 3rd party site?

Comment: Actually i bought the JomSocial old pack 2.4.
The Jomsocial 2.8.x i took from 3rd party site.

Comment: hmm well you shouldn't be asking for support on Stackoverflow for an extension that you have downloaded elsewhere, even if you did buy a previous version. My suggestions would be to update your JomSocial subscription and contact the developers for support.

Answer (score 1):

open the installation package 
there is a file inside called
install.community.php

search for this code

```
if (JVERSION < '2.5.6' and $communityVersion >= '2.8.0')
```

change to

```
if (JVERSION < '2.5.10' and $communityVersion >= '2.8.0')
```